# JDBC prepared statement with large no columns causing performance bottleneck. How ETL tools circumvent this issue?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Mainly a DB guy  and did not use java for Bulk loading etc. as those were done by ETL tools or DB internal tools.

But if I understand correctly Tools are written by Java/C++ etc. and they are using JDBC,ODBC  to implement operation .

Recently in one project  trying to load bulk data using JDBC  and observed the following .

we have one million records, 1.5 Gb of data  , the table is with 360 columns .
Reading from Table A  and trying to insert in Target table in  5k records Batch mode interval. source abd target is Oracle.

The project uses Spring JDBC. I have used here simple JDBC to test stand alone  and debugging the performance issue . 
 the logic described  in pseudo language .

```
prepare statement for Target with 
"insert into target values ( ?,?, .. 368 columns);
rs = (  select * from table a );
while rs.next {
  stmt.setstring(1, rs.getString("column1");
 .
 .
 360 columns.
 stmt.add_batch();

 if 5K records then executeBatch();
}
```

Main issue:

for every 5K records the set Statements are  taking around more than 1 minute.

so loading just 1.5 Gb or 1 million rec will take approx. 4 hours.

I am doing it in a single thread but I feel the volume is very low. 
Is there any better way to implement this?

How ETL tools say informatica etc. implements internally?

The other issue is: sometimes `executeBatch()` for some table with similar no of columns  and more volume per record  write 5k records in one go. In some cases it writes 100 records in one go  though `executeBatch` is after 5k rows and write also takes eternity for 1 million records.

One more thing instead of result set if I use the set statements as

```
for (I=1 ,I<=1000000; I++)
  stmt.setstring(1, rs.getString("123456789");--hardcode value
    .
    .
    360 columns.
   stmt.add_batch();
  if 5K records then executeBatch();
}
```

then it takes around 4 seconds to bind for every 5k and 2-3  secs to `executeBatch()`. So in 20 mins I am able to load 1 million around 6-7 GB of data.

Comment: Did you very that it's in fact the `setString()`  that is taking the time, and not the processing of the ResultSet through `rs.next()` and `rs.getString()`?

Comment: yes in min query finishes. moreover when I do this in PL/SQL  with cursor for loop with individual insert and commit after every 4k records 1 million gets inserted in 150 sec. Understand in Java it will take time but currently it is taking 4-5 hours . I am puzzled .

Comment: what's the latencies between source db <> client java <> remote db ?

Comment: the latency is negligible . moreover just to test it I am using Java client and target DB to simulate source ,java and target. I am reading from target 6 GB partitioned table  and in target itself writing the data back to a new empty table.

Comment: Are you sure it's the "large number of columns"? e.g. what is performance like with fewer columns, or without the `insert`? Row by row processing inevitably has an overhead though. It has always been considered poor practice in PL/SQL, and that is without the additional overhead of pulling the data out of the database and pushing it back in again.

Comment: The binding  and resultset issue is resolved. I was not using setFetchSize . I set it to 3000 and binding  for 5 K  is completing  in 5 secs. The second issue is I put not null value in all the 360 columns and I was able to fetch and load  .1 million recs in 2 min 20 sec. But the actual data has around 80% columns null  and then it is taking time to load. executeBatch is not working properly . it is inserting record in between 15  and 20 .  and to load 5k it is taking time. I saw somewhere it is an issue with JDBC driver.

Comment: I agree with ur point of row by row processing . It is abt DBAs they will not allow DB link for unknown reason . Which is a 100 lines of PL/SQL code now all these complexities is introduced.

Comment: Using setObject of JDBC . when columns are large i.e. more than 250 etc. and have 80% attributes have null values then it is abnormally slow . with SetString,setBigDecimal,setdate it is fine  though CPU utilization is high and GC behaves abnormally .

Comment: As I was using standalone Java & did some primitive java Prog memory etc.  still I was able to load 70k rows with  360 columns with any value in one minute and Spring  was taking 30 mins.. Issue is with Spring framework and those who r using it  to set the parameters to correct values . conveyed to Java programmers .  the GC and memory issue is due to I was using command line java as I do not hv access to IDE etc & was not interested in further R&D.